# dynamically push object into nested array based on key,value pair condition

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, nested-object

I have the following object:

```
{type=stuff, name=blablabla, variableId=x, fingerprint=xxxx, containerId=xxxx, accountId=xxxx, workspaceId=xxx, path=accounts/xxxx/containers/xxxx/workspaces/xx/variables/x, parentFolderId=x, parameter=[{value=auto, type=template, key=xxxxx}, {type=boolean, key=asdasdf, value=false}, {value=false, type=boolean, key=adasdasd}, {type=boolean, value=false, key=asdasdasd}, {type=list, key=fieldsToSet, list=[{map=[{value=asdasdas, type=template, key=asdasdas}, {value=asdasdas, type=template, key=value}], type=map}, {type=map, map=[{type=template, value=page, key=fieldName}, {type=template, key=value, value=asdasdasd}]}]}, {value=false, type=boolean, key=asdasd}, {type=boolean, value=false, key=asdasdasd}, {value=false, type=boolean, key=adasdasd}, {key=dimension, type=list, list=[{type=map, map=[{value=2, key=index, type=template}, {value=asdasd, type=template, key=dimension}]}, {type=map, map=[{value=3, type=template, key=index}, {value=asdasdasd, type=template, key=dimension}]}, {map=[{type=template, value=4, key=index}, {key=dimension, type=template, value=asdasdasd / asdasdasd}], type=map}, {map=[{type=template, value=5, key=index}, {value=asdasd, type=template, key=dimension}], type=map}, {type=map, map=[{value=6, type=template, key=index}, {key=dimension, type=template, value=asdasdasd}]}, {map=[{type=template, key=index, value=7}, {value=asdasd, type=template, key=dimension}], type=map}, {type=map, map=[{key=index, value=8, type=template}, {value=asdasdasd, key=dimension, type=template}]}]}, {key=enableEcommerce, type=boolean, value=false}, {value=asdasdasd, type=template, key=asdasdasd}], tagManagerUrl=https://blabla.com/#/asdasd/accounts/asdasd/containers/xxxxx/workspaces/xxxx/variables/x?apiLink=variable}
```

I want to modify it and add this object `{type=map, map=[{key=fieldName, value=cookieExpires, type=template}, {key=value, value=33696000, type=template}]}` into the nested object with the key `fieldsToSet`.

So far I've tried something like this but it doesn't work:

```
element.parameter.filter(obj => { return obj.key === "fieldsToSet" }).push(newObject);
```

I need something dynamic as the number of object and arrays always change.

Comment: Assign it to in list array variable. And run loop and in that loop use if condition for your require array format and store it in dictionary variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to add `newObject` to `element.parameter[]` using Google Apps Script.

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `element.parameter.filter(obj => { return obj.key === "fieldsToSet" })` returns the object including `obj.key === "fieldsToSet"`. By this, when `push(newObject)` is used for this, `newObject` is added to the retrieved element. I think that this might be the reason of your issue.

In this answer, I would like to propose the following modified script. In this sample script, I converted your value to the JSON object because I thought that your sample value might be directly obtained from the object with `Logger.log`.

#### Modified script:

```js
var element = {"type":"stuff","name":"blablabla","variableId":"x","fingerprint":"xxxx","containerId":"xxxx","accountId":"xxxx","workspaceId":"xxx","path":"accounts/xxxx/containers/xxxx/workspaces/xx/variables/x","parentFolderId":"x","parameter":[{"value":"auto","type":"template","key":"xxxxx"},{"type":"boolean","key":"asdasdf","value":false},{"value":false,"type":"boolean","key":"adasdasd"},{"type":"boolean","value":false,"key":"asdasdasd"},{"type":"list","key":"fieldsToSet","list":[{"map":[{"value":"asdasdas","type":"template","key":"asdasdas"},{"value":"asdasdas","type":"template","key":"value"}],"type":"map"},{"type":"map","map":[{"type":"template","value":"page","key":"fieldName"},{"type":"template","key":"value","value":"asdasdasd"}]}]},{"value":false,"type":"boolean","key":"asdasd"},{"type":"boolean","value":false,"key":"asdasdasd"},{"value":false,"type":"boolean","key":"adasdasd"},{"key":"dimension","type":"list","list":[{"type":"map","map":[{"value":2,"key":"index","type":"template"},{"value":"asdasd","type":"template","key":"dimension"}]},{"type":"map","map":[{"value":3,"type":"template","key":"index"},{"value":"asdasdasd","type":"template","key":"dimension"}]},{"map":[{"type":"template","value":4,"key":"index"},{"key":"dimension","type":"template","value":"asdasdasd / asdasdasd"}],"type":"map"},{"map":[{"type":"template","value":5,"key":"index"},{"value":"asdasd","type":"template","key":"dimension"}],"type":"map"},{"type":"map","map":[{"value":6,"type":"template","key":"index"},{"key":"dimension","type":"template","value":"asdasdasd"}]},{"map":[{"type":"template","key":"index","value":7},{"value":"asdasd","type":"template","key":"dimension"}],"type":"map"},{"type":"map","map":[{"key":"index","value":8,"type":"template"},{"value":"asdasdasd","key":"dimension","type":"template"}]}]},{"key":"enableEcommerce","type":"boolean","value":false},{"value":"asdasdasd","type":"template","key":"asdasdasd"}],"tagManagerUrl":"https://blabla.com/#/asdasd/accounts/asdasd/containers/xxxxx/workspaces/xxxx/variables/x?apiLink=variable"};

var newObject = {"type":"map","map":[{"key":"fieldName","value":"cookieExpires","type":"template"},{"key":"value","value":33696000,"type":"template"}]};

element.parameter.forEach(({key},_,a) => {
  if (key === "fieldsToSet") {
    a.push(newObject);
  }
});
console.log(element);
```

#### Note:

- Above sample value of `element` was converted from your sample value in your question. So when my conversion is not correct, please modify or replcace with your actual value.
- For example, when you add `newObject` to `element.parameter[].list[]`, you can use the following script.

  ```
    element.parameter.forEach(obj => {
      if (obj.key === "fieldsToSet") {
        obj.list.push(newObject);
      }
    });
  ```

#### References:

- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)